# Is it good idea to write unittests, which will check whether important templates are in right place?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-templates

I am wondering, should we check in our application, whether for instance TEMPLATE_DIRS is properly configured.

Moreover, sometime some application can use it owm base.html, maybe unittest should check whether application use proper base.html template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be bothered with testing the internals of Django. Its very rare in my experience for the settings to change without anyone noticing. TDD is not just about testing everything to make people on your team, or yourself happy. OOP makes you feel confident testing everything, but what if things change? will you be fixing all the tests before adding a new feature? too much burden!